# How can I activate Reg-Ex when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce checkout page, I am using a reg-ex in my phone text. It works smoothly. But this doesn't work while the page is loading. So, if the phone number is entered, it is displayed as follows:
0000000000
If I click on the label it turns into what I want:
000-000-0000
So if the label is not clicked, it looks adjacent. How can I solve this problem. My code is below:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'a_format_checkout_billing_phone');
function a_format_checkout_billing_phone() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( function($){
                $('#billing_phone').on( 'input focusout', function() {
                    var p = $(this).val();

                    p = p.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    p = p.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
                    $(this).val(p);
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

**Updated Code 2021 May 3**
This code is now working fine.

```
    add_action('wp_footer', 'a_format_checkout_billing_phone');
        function a_format_checkout_billing_phone() {
            if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery( function($){
                        $('#billing_phone').on( 'input focusout', function() {
                            var p = $(this).val();
        
$('#billing_phone').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
                    p = p.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    p = p.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
                    $(this).val(p);
                });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            <?php
            endif;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger input with this `$("#billing_phone").trigger("input");`

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'a_format_checkout_billing_phone');
function a_format_checkout_billing_phone() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( function($){
                $('#billing_phone').on( 'input focusout', function() {
                    var p = $(this).val();
                    p = p.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    p = p.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
                    $(this).val(p);
                });
                $("#billing_phone").trigger("input");
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

```js
$('#billing_phone').on( 'input focusout', function() {
    var p = $(this).val();
    p = p.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    p = p.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
    $(this).val(p);
});
$("#billing_phone").trigger("input");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value="123456789101112" autocomplete="tel">
```

Comment: Update:
There's a problem. If I write trigger, Wordpress function (wc_add_notice) does not work in case of any error. The page does not go to the top (page to tap). Are there any solution ?

Comment: Update(2): I solved the problem as follows:  $('#billing_phone').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {//codes });